# python games problem

Tags: python

I have made a mine sweeper game which fully works except for one key point,  which is:

> Allow the player to place flags on
>   cells to mark mine locations and to
>   remove flags.  if a cell is marked
>   with a flag the player can not
>   activate it by clicking on it.

Now I don't know how to do this flag requirement.

Comment: Don't know how to do it using your current game library (what is the library, then?) or don't know how to do it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking for a hint on how to do that, a safe way to go is to make the playfield a 2D array and each item of the array an object holding certain information. (In your case that's probably a boolean telling whether the cell contains a mine and a boolean telling whether the cell is marked or not.)

Comment: If you were implementing something similar to Microsoft's minesweeper, you would need more than a bool, as a given square can have multiple states

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list for each specific tile in the game, and its attributes eg. number (int), flagged (bool), death_tile (bool) and more.  You can then put:

```
if not [square coordinate] [flagged]:
    open_tile()
```

Replace `[square coordinate]` with its value in the list, and `[flagged]` with the data value saying if it is flagged or not.  `open_tile()` would be replaced by the function that reveals the tile.